# Create a folder with the date as part of the name in tcsh

Tags: command-line, mkdir, tcsh

I often need to create folders that start with the current date.

For example 190627_ABCD.

I've tried to create an alias command that gets the date to be printed:

```
a newf 'mkdir `date '+%y%m%d'_`+='
```

But this results in printing up the += at the end, which I was trying to use as an instruction to concatenate.

The idea being that I can add the ABCD in the command.  So to get 190627_ABCD I type in the shell:

```
newf ABCD
```

But it isn't working for me.  Grateful for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [Writing Aliases in csh and tcsh](https://home.adelphi.edu/sbloch/class/archive/271/fall2005/notes/aliases.html), you can use history expansion (since, in csh, history expansion occurs before alias expansion):

```
myhost:~> alias newf 'mkdir -v `date "+%y%m%d_\!:1"`'
myhost:~> newf ABCD
mkdir: created directory '190627_ABCD'
```

Comment: or: `alias newf 'mkdir -v \`date +%y%m%d_\!^\`'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want your alias to accept multiple arguments (as well), use the history expansion `!*` and `foreach` to loop over them:

```sh
foreach name (!*)
  mkdir -v `date +%y%m%d_"$name"`
end
```

#### Example

```sh
myhost:~> alias newf 'foreach name (\!*)\
? mkdir -v `date +%y%m%d_"$name"`\
? end'
myhost:~> alias
newf    foreach name (!*)
mkdir -v `date +%y%m%d_"$name"`
end
myhost:~> newf a b
mkdir: created directory '190627_a'
mkdir: created directory '190627_b'
```